# Angular firebase user authentication error (type error)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am following a course on how to design authentication using firebase and angular. Everything was running okay until I faced this error in the function named getCurrentUser().

Here is the error message

(error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<firebase.User, User>' is not assignable
to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<User | null, User>'.
Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'User'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'.)

Do you have any idea how this might be solved

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'
import { User as FirebaseUser } from 'firebase'
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

import { IUser, User } from '../user/user'
import { Role } from './auth.enum'
import {
  AuthService,
  IAuthStatus,
  IServerAuthResponse,
  defaultAuthStatus,
} from './auth.service'

interface IJwtToken {
  email: string
  iat: number
  exp: number
  sub: string
}
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseAuthService extends AuthService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    super()
  }
  protected authProvider(
    email: string,
    password: string
  ): Observable<IServerAuthResponse> {
    const serverResponse$ = new Subject<IServerAuthResponse>()
    this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      (res) => {
        const firebaseUser: FirebaseUser | null = res.user
        firebaseUser?.getIdToken().then(
          (token) => serverResponse$.next({ accessToken: token } as IServerAuthResponse),
          (err) => serverResponse$.error(err)
        )
      },
      (err) => serverResponse$.error(err)
    )
    return serverResponse$
  }
  protected transformJwtToken(token: IJwtToken): IAuthStatus {
    if (!token) {
      return defaultAuthStatus
    }
    return {
      isAuthenticated: token.email ? true : false,
      userId: token.sub,
      userRole: Role.None,
    }
  }
  protected getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.afAuth.user.pipe(map(this.transformFirebaseUser))
  }
  private transformFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser): User {
    if (!firebaseUser) {
      return new User()
    }
    return User.Build({
      name: {
        first: firebaseUser?.displayName?.split(' ')[0] || 'Firebase',
        last: firebaseUser?.displayName?.split(' ')[1] || 'User',
      },
      picture: firebaseUser.photoURL,
      email: firebaseUser.email,
      _id: firebaseUser.uid,
      role: Role.None,
    } as IUser)
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  logout() {
    if (this.afAuth) {
      this.afAuth.signOut()
    }
    this.clearToken()
    this.authStatus$.next(defaultAuthStatus)
  }
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Probably this line: `const firebaseUser: FirebaseUser | null = res.user`. Is there a reason for the `| null`?

Comment: yes indeed! It seems that this is the locus of the problem. Do you have an approach to fix it. @GunnarB.

Comment: I tried delete it. It persists

Comment: Not quite sure. Is the course older?  Maybe the api changed a bit. From what I saw I think it should `this.afAuth.currentUser.getIdToken()`, maybe even `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken`.

Answer (score 0):

Please import these 2 :

1. import firebase  from 'firebase/app'
2. import 'firebase/auth'

Then change the private transformFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser): User to  private transformFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: firebase.User): User and const firebaseUser: FirebaseUser | null = res.user to const firebaseUser: firebaseUser.User | null = res.user. These changes are based on the source code given by the author itself, the book is slightly different from the source code [here]:https://github.com/duluca/lemon-mart/

But one more change is the private transformFirebaseUser(firebaseUser: firebase.User | null): User.

In my understanding, the getCurrentUser() creating a User object using the transformFirebaseUser which it is only called after login is clicked, the transformFirebaseUser function has a parameter with firebaseUser.User , but it could be null. Hover over this.afAuth.user if you are using Visual Studio Code, then you can see that the Observable type is <firebase.User | null>, the transformFireBaseUser need to match when using firebase.User as parameter.